# How to create a click listener on the head of every quiver 3D plot in matlab?

Tags: matlab, 3d, visualization, onclicklistener

I want to create a plot which has listeners to every item which is plotted. What I actually want to do is to create a 3D quiver plot, and whenever I click on the head of the arrow, I want to create another plot based on the ID of the arrow clicked.

Is this possible in Matlab?

I am open to exploring other options (which are easy to implement) in other programming languages.

Comment: Well, it's possible...but it'll take a bit more than 2 lines of code. What is the level of complexity you had in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Graphics handle objects have [callbacks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f7-55518.html) that you can use for this kind of thing.

> ButtonDownFcn — Executes when you click the left mouse button while
>   the cursor is over the object or within a 5-pixel border around the
>   object.

You can also set the `'UserData'` [property of each graphics handle object](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_guis/f13-998352.html), in your case to give it an ID.

Combine these two concepts to create the functionality that you want:

```
h = quiver(...); %# generate the graphics handle item;
set(h,'UserData',1,'ButtonDownFcn',@myCallback);

function myCallback(src,eventdata)
    clicked_item_id = get(src,'UserData'); %# get the ID of the clicked item
    figure; plot(data(ID)); %# obviously won't work as is, just for illustration
end
```

Comment: thanks, that is what I was looking for, just like javascript callbacks